# SQLCMD: Pass parameter database startig with number to script using powershell

Tags: sql, database, powershell, numbers, sqlcmd

From **powershell** we are running the following command to create a Database. The database name starts with a **number**:

```
SQLCMD -S Z0EUW1WLSQL031\PRUEBA -U rdb00001 -P "1234" -v datos="`"D:\Datos\`""  dbName="3DataBase" log="`"E:\Logs\`"" collation="Latin1_General_CI_AS" -i 10_CreateDB.sql -o 10_CreateDB.log
```

The script "10_CreateDB.sql" contains this:

```
CREATE DATABASE $(dbName)  ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = N'$(dbName)', FILENAME = N'$(datos)$(dbName).mdf' )
 LOG ON
( NAME = N'$(dbName)_log', FILENAME = N'$(log)$(dbName)_log.ldf'  )
COLLATE $(collation)
GO
```

We are getting this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server Z0EUW1WLSQL031\PRUEBA, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '3'.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ArgumentList = @(
    '-S Z0EUW1WLSQL031\PRUEBA',
    '-U rdb00001',
    '-P "1234"',
    '-v datos="D:\Datos\"',
    'dbName="3DataBase" ',
    'log="E:\Logs\"',
    'collation="Latin1_General_CI_AS"',
    '-i 10_CreateDB.sql',
    '-o 10_CreateDB.log'
)

Start-Process "fullPathHere\SQLCMD.exe" -ArgumentList $ArgumentList
```

Comment: How can we replace the parameter values (for example: "rdb00001") by variables within the variable $ArgumentList?

Comment: Still getting error:

`Start-Process "SQLCMD" -ArgumentList -S Z0EUW1WLSQL031\PRUEBA -U rdb00001 -P "1234" -v datos=""D:\Datos\"" dbName="3DataBase" log="":\Logs\"" collation="Latin1_General_CI_AS" -i 10_CreateDB.sql -o 10_CreateDB.log

Cannot find path '10_CreateDB.log' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (10_CreateDB.log:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : S0EUL1WYSQL050`

S0EUL1WYSQL050 is where the command is run.

Comment: you need to specify the full path to the file, and the arguments can be put into an array